# Handling impatient users during semi-long async requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, identityserver4

We're running an IdentityServer4 on .NET Core. Currently users log in with their AzureAD accounts - if the username is not found in the database then we query Microsoft's Graph API to get their groups, general information and more.

Recently an application made two login requests pretty much back to back - since the user didn't exist it made the query and added their account to the database *twice*.

I've been searching for the best way to deal with this but from what I've read pretty much all solutions are considered bad practice.

The setup is like this - after login a user is directed to the AccountController - ExternalLoginCallback:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
....
var user = await _users.AutoProvisionUser(provider, userId, externalUser, access_token, _options); // _users is the UserStore class
...
}
```

AutoProvisionUser looks like this:

```
public async Task<User> AutoProvisionUser(string provider, string userId, ClaimsPrincipal principal, string accessToken, Globals globals)
        {

            var user = await GetFullUserByUsernameAsync(principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimConstants.UPN));

            if (user.Account == null)
            {
                user = await CreateUserAsync(principal, userId, accessToken, globals.AzureApplication);
            }
            else
            {
                await UpdateGroupsAsync(user.Account, accessToken, globals.AzureApplication);
            }

            return new User
            {
                Claims = principal.Claims.ToList(),
                Name = user.Profile.DisplayName,
                Provider = provider,
                SubjectId = user.Account.AzureId,
                Username = user.Account.UserName
            };

        }
```

```
public async Task<UserIdentity> CreateUserAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal, string userId, string graphAccessToken,
            AzureApplication options)
        {
        // API calls to Microsoft, adding them to the database and then returning the user...
        }
```

I've been thinking of making a method that queues all the tasks and waiting for them to complete before continuing - would this resolve the problem or would another request simply spin up a new thread and ignore the current execution?

I've also been thinking of adding a custom **DelegateHandler** and try to use some logic there to see if I'm able to filter out "duplicate" requests.

The absolute best I'd assume is that if another duplicate request is made the application waits for any **CreateUserAsync** task that is currently running before doing the **user.Account == null** check. Is that practical to implement and if so is it by wrapping the tasks like I mentioned above?

Comment: There's no unique index in the database to prevent duplicates accounts?

Comment: Not at the moment but that might be the way forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any form of in-memory queue or handler is just going to be a band-aid, because what happens when you need to scale to a second web server?

The proper solution is to enforce this at the lowest level; i.e., in your database. The second write to the database would fail, at which point your code could re-attempt its read. This is a form of [optimistic concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control).